# Change language to english after "software boutique" upgraded into a different language

Tags: ubuntu-mate, software-boutique

I chose to update the listings using the button that exists on the bottom left (I don't know what it says because it is no longer there).
Now, after upgrading, it is in a different language that is not english, although the OS is configured to be in english.

How do I change the language back to english?